# Celery how to stop tasks being processed on a developnent machine

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have my **production** and **development** machines setup using **Celery** in **Django**. Everything works. My issue is that when I boot up my development machine it **starts to consume tasks** and if I have a bug (which I often do on my development version) this can give me lots of headaches.

I still want my development machine to send tasks to be consumed, but how do I stop it from processing tasks and leave just my production server for that?

PS, I don't want to have to remove celery setting on my development machine as I still want my dev one to send tasks to be consumed, if that makes sense.

These are my current settings...

**Celery**

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://admin:xyz@54.111.111.11:5672//'
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
```

I'm using RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
celery purge
```

And if you have django-celery you can do

```
python manage.py celery purge
```